# Used iMac just boots to Utilities, can't reinstall OS or sign in under my Apple ID

Tags: imac, apfs

Trying to update an iMac (2015, I believe?) a friend gave me. They've fully signed out of it, and I have erased the hard drive in disk utilities, but I cannot get it to boot to anything. When I choose to install OS, it loads El Capitan, and when I try to sign in, it says "This item is temporarily unavailable." The message boards I've read say to wipe the drive and format to APFS, but that doesn't show up in the options.

I'm generally computer-literate, but this is just deeply frustrating me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Internet Recovery should be available.  Try `Opt-Cmd-R` while booting.  You will be asked for WiFi credentials.  It will download the latest compatible version of macOS for your iMac.

Comment: Won't be possible with those old ones since they can't do APFS. You need a clone with a more recent operating system to repartition the internal drive from.

Comment: A 2015 iMac can most definitely  support APFS @JohnSonnino

Comment: I just installed an SSD in a late 2013 iMac and it booted with Maverics and wasn't able to repartition its drive to APFS to update to a newer OS. Wasn't sure if that would still be the case here, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: "Apple File System was announced at Apple's developers' conference (WWDC) in June 2016 as a replacement for HFS+, which had been in use since 1998." Cited from wikipedia

Comment: Your 2013 also supports APFS.  In fact, it is supported with at least Catalina.  APFS was not available until High Sierra so you won’t get it using Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (and only) way I know would be to:

1. Download Carbon Copy Cloner onto another apple computer with an up-to-date operating system. Do not start the trial until the next step in case you don't have all the necessary parts i.e. external hard drive with enough space.
2. Make a clone of another apple computer with an up-to-date operating system onto an external drive. (using the trial version of CCC)
3. Plug this clone via the external drive to USB to the computer you are working on and open the computer by holding the option `alt` key whilst turning on. Select the external drive to boot using the clone.
4. Now you can open disk utility and disk utility is recent enough to have APFS. You can now erase the original (internal) disk and choose APFS for the new partition.
5. Now start the computer you are working on by holding the command `cmd`, option `alt` and r `R` keys in order to do an internet recovery using the latest operating system possible, which given that your internal hard drive is now APFS, you can have the latest available. Everything rolls on easily from here.

-- Edit -- I see you have already upvoted the first answer so quick fyi, if your internal drive still isn't APFS, you might be stuck with an old OS. I was when I installed a new SSD on an iMac recently. If that's the case, you can reformat the internal drive to APFS using the steps above, when updating OS isn't possible.